# getting error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class budgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       
    budget_used        = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    budget_remain      = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_budget       = serializers.IntegerField(default=250000)


    def get_budget_used (self,obj):
            budget_used=budget.objects.filter(user=obj.user).aggregate(Sum('budget_stord__bytes'))
            data = []
            for val in budget_used.items():
                if val.value > total_budget :
                    raise serializers.ValidationError('you exceed the total budget limit')
           
            return f'budget : {(budget_used/1000)} '

    def get_total_budget(self,obj):
            total_budget = 250000
            return f'total_budget: {(total_budget/1000)} '   
    def get_remain(self,obj):
            remain = (total_budget) - (budget_used)   
            return remain

    class Meta:
        model  = budget_u
        fields = ("budget_used","total_budget","budget_remain")
```

```
MODEl 

class budget_u(CreatedModel, UUIDPKModel):
    budget_stord = models.ForeignKey('bud.Store', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.user', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=False, blank=False)
```

I need output like

```
{
    " budget_used": "100",
    "remain": "150G",
    "total_budget": "250"
}
```

getting
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: `budget_used.items()` returns a *two-tuple iterable*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not access the value with `.value`, `.items()` returns an iterable of 2-tuples, so you can use iterable unpacking in the `for` loop. But here you can simply use subscripting to access the value:

```
def get_budget_used(self, obj):
    budget_used = budget_u.objects.filter(
        user=obj.user
    ).aggregate(total=Sum('budget_stord__bytes'))['total'] or 0
    if budget_used > 250000:
        return 'you exceed the total budget limit'
    return f'budget : {(budget_used/1000)}'
```

That being said, it is rather *odd* to each time return strings. Often serializers return numeric data, since that is easier to process, for example by a JavaScript script at the browser side, or an integration of the client.

Comment: Thank you Willem Van Onsem , when i used your code i am getting this Error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: @user1007061: I assume that is because there is no related `budget_u` object? You can use `or 0` in that case.

Comment: hey in the code above ,when i run the code i get  for my remain.                                             def get_remain(self,obj):
           remain = (self.context.get(total_budget)) - (self.context.get(budget_used))   
            return remain                                                                                   Error       remain = (self.context.get(total_budget)) - (self.context.get(budget_used))  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: But `self.context` has *no* `total_budget`, nor `budget_used`. `context` only contains objects you pass to the serializer yourself. Even if it had that, that would not work, since your methods return *string*s, not numbers, hence substracting is not possible. THis is one of the (many) reaons why using strings as response is not a good idea.

Comment: I am new in Django and python can you please explain me more ,, because when i used only obj.get_total_budget . it is also did not work

Comment: how can i substract the Total and Used to git the remaining , do you think i should used Model in instated of Serilaizer